# decoupled design for async http request

Tags: android, http, javafx, design-patterns

What i am trying to write is a view-> controller -> model -> client -> HttpRequestSender relationship that is abstract, so i can replace the HttpRequestSender when i am using different platform (android-volley, Fx-SpringRest). since on android i need to use a-non main thread to preform the HttpRequest, my solution was to use a callback that is sent from the controller down throw the chain to enable the asynchronous behavior needed.

My issue is that all though it is a working solution, the code becomes highly
hard to follow.

So that a simple method like `registerDevice(String name)` - as seen below:

```
public class DeviceRegModel {

    DeviceClient client;

    DeviceInfoMgr deviceInfoMgr;

    public void registerDevice(String name) throws DeviceNameTakenException {
        checkIfNameTaken(name);

        Device device = client.createDevice().getBody();

        device.setName(name);

        client.updateDevice(device);

        deviceInfoMgr.set(name);
    }

    private void checkIfNameTaken(String name) throws DeviceNameTakenException {
        for(Device dev : client.getAllDevices()) {
            if(dev.getName() == name) {
                throw new DeviceNameTakenException();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Becomes that:**

```
public class DeviceRegModel implements IModel {



DeviceClient client;

    DeviceInfoMgr deviceInfoMgr;


    public void registerDevice(String name, HttpCallback callback)   {
        ResponseCommand onOk = (res) -> checkIfNameTaken(name, res, callback);
        HttpFailCommands onFail = callback.getOnFailCmds();

        client.getAllDevices(HttpCallback.build(onOk, onFail));

    }

    private void checkIfNameTaken(String name, IResponse res, HttpCallback callback)  {
        for(Device dev : res.<Device[]>getBody()) {
            if(dev.getName() == name) {
                ExceptionCommand failCmd = callback.getOnFailCmds().getInternalFailCmd();
                failCmd.execute(new DeviceNameTakenException());
            }
        }
        createDevice(name,callback);
    }

    private void createDevice(String name, HttpCallback callback) {
        ResponseCommand onOk = (res) -> setNameLocally(name, res, callback);
        HttpFailCommands onFail = callback.getOnFailCmds();

        client.createDevice(HttpCallback.build(onOk, onFail));
    }

    private void setNameLocally(String name, IResponse res, HttpCallback callback) {
        Device device = res.<Device>getBody();
        device.setName(name);

        ResponseCommand onOk = (cmdRes) -> updateServer(name, cmdRes, callback);
        HttpFailCommands onFail = callback.getOnFailCmds();

        client.updateDevice(device, HttpCallback.build(onOk, onFail));
    }

    private void updateServer(String name, IResponse res, HttpCallback callback) {
        deviceInfoMgr.set(name);
        callback.getOnOkCmd().execute(res);
    }
}
```

I am trying to figure out if i am on the correct path here (with the second version) **or should change my design?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to compose computations that may involve a lot of asynchronous steps, there aren't any really good options that will let you write super-clean code.

Of the options that *are* available -- event-driven design, continuation passing, monads, etc., monads are the modern choice, because they let you write asynchronous code that has the same basic structure as the equivalent synchronous code.  It's still won't be very pretty code, but at least it's built of the same functional blocks.

In JavaScript the asynchronous monad is Promise, and in Java it's CompletionStage/CompletableFuture.  This is what your class looks like in that style (I'm assuming all the calls to `client` are async and return a CompletionStage):

```
DeviceClient client;

DeviceInfoMgr deviceInfoMgr;

public CompletionStage<Void> registerDevice(String name) {

    return checkIfNameTaken(name)
        .thenCompose( (unused) -> client.createDevice())
        .thenCompose(deviceResponse -> {
            Device device = deviceResponse.getBody();
            device.setName(name);
            return client.updateDevice(device);
        }).thenApply(unused -> {
            deviceInfoMgr.set(name);
            return (Void)null;
        });
}

private CompletionStage<Void> checkIfNameTaken(String name) {

    return client.getAllDevices()
        .thenCompose(devices -> {

            for(Device dev : devices) {
                if(dev.getName() == name) {
                    //I use a helper for this
                    CompletableFuture<Void> err = new CompletableFuture<>();
                    err.completeExceptionally(new DeviceNameTakenException());
                    return err;
                }
            }
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture((Void)null);
        });
}
```

You see that it has the same methods that it had before, and those methods do the same thing they did before, and they do it with the same sequence of operations... but now they return a CompletionStage, indicating that they may run asynchronously and the results may depend on things that aren't done when those methods return.

Comment: That exactly what i was looking for! Thank you very much!